# Watermark in Autodesk translated file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a platform where I am showing a 3D models mapped with 2D models. I want to know if there is any way to add watermark on 3D/2D model while loading in javascript viewer.

Your help would be appreciated with sample logic.

Comment: You can add svg like this : https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-svg-your-2d-sheets-forge-viewer ?

Comment: Hi @AlexAR, we are having dynamic watermark content and need to show diagonally in viewer from left bottom to right top cornor. I am not able to load extension "Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore" in v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js. could you share some code example for above viewer3d js?